# Cutpoints in a maze

Tags: code-golf, graph-theory, restricted-time, maze, binary-matrix

A maze is given as a matrix of 0s (walls) and 1s (walkable space) in any convenient format. Each cell is considered connected to its 4 (or fewer) orthogonal neighbours. A *connected component* is a set of walkable cells all transitively connected to each other. Your task is to identify the *cutpoints* - walkable cells which, if turned into walls, would change the number of connected components. Output a boolean matrix with 1-s only at those locations. The goal is to do it in the fewest bytes of code.

The input matrix will consist of at least 3 rows and 3 columns. At least one of its cells will be a wall and at least one will be walkable. Your function or program must be able to process any of the examples below in under a minute on [TIO](https://tio.run/) (or on your own computer, if the language is not supported by TIO).

```
in:
11101001
11011101
00000001
11101111
11110101
00011111
10110001
11111111
out:
01000000
00001001
00000001
00000101
00110000
00010000
00000000
11100000

in:
1111111111111111
1000000000000001
1111111111111101
0000000000000101
1111111111110101
1000000000010101
1011111111010101
1010000001010101
1010111101010101
1010101111010101
1010100000010101
1010111111110101
1010000000000101
1011111111111101
1000000000000001
1111111111111111
out:
0000000000000000
0000000000000000
0000000000000000
0000000000000000
0000000000000000
0000000000000000
0000000000000000
0000000000000000
0000000000000000
0000000000000000
0000000000000000
0000000000000000
0000000000000000
0000000000000000
0000000000000000
0000000000000000

in:
1011010001111010
1111111011101101
1110010101001011
1111001110010010
1111010000101001
0111101001000101
0011100111110010
1001110011111110
0101000011100011
1110110101001110
0010100111000110
1000110111011010
0100101000100101
0001010101100011
1001010000111101
1000111011000010
out:
0000000000111010
1011110001001000
0000000000000011
0000000100010000
0000010000101000
0000001000000100
0000000011000000
1001100000011110
0000000001000010
0110100001000110
0000100101000010
1000100000000000
0100001000000100
0000000100100001
0000010000111000
0000010000000010
```

Comment: so, find all bridges in all subgraphs

Comment: I think that the challenge would benefit from a step-by-step example for a smaller matrix.

Comment: @HyperNeutrino yes, except I tried to use mainstream graph-theoretic terminology

Comment: ok. (..pretty sure they are called bridges formally but idk lol)

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder There are multiple possible approaches for solving this. I prefer not to describe any particular algorithm.

Comment: @HyperNeutrino a _bridge_ is something different - it's an *edge* (not a vertex) whose removal increases the number of connected components

Comment: @HyperNeutrino also, a _subgraph_ is not quite the same as a _connected component_

Comment: oh right, it does slightly differ. nvm

Comment: @HyperNeutrino "bridge"? I think it should be articulation point.

Comment: Can we choose other characters than `01` in input and/or output ?

Comment: @TonHospel sure, you can also use 01 as numbers or true/false if you language has a boolean type, whichever is most convenient

Comment: Isn’t a cutpoint [usually defined](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ArticulationVertex.html) to be a vertex whose deletion *increases* the number of components, not just changes the number? Your definition counts isolated vertices as cutpoints, but this one doesn’t.

Comment: @Notatree You're right. I made a mistake. It's too late to fix it now but I hope it won't spoil the fun.

Comment: I originally lost 5 bytes to fix this behaviour for isolated vertices but by now I optimzed it so much that it would be longer to not count them :-)

Comment: @TonHospel huh, i thought it would be just a matter of < vs !=

Comment: @ngn a test case about isolated vertices? 000,010,000 -> 000,010,000 ?

Comment: @edc65 the third test case has some of those

Answer (score 3):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 26 bytes

```
n:"GG0@(,w4&1ZIuz]=~]vGZye
```

The input is a numerical matrix, using `;` as row separator.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/P89Kyd3dwEFDp9xEzTDKs7Qq1rYutsw9qjL1//9oQwUQNABjIGkN50Jpa7A4AkJVINTABWCmwLUYIqswgKpAMQMOYwE) Or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##pVO7DsIwDNz5iooBMTDYEhMWEgMLmRmqVpFAiA2YeAgGfj1A1bq2k2ZBVh@J7s6xcz7vr6ewK124LMbOwWo6e8wnWG1uL798@7urnscAh3K9DTUWv4Dm@b6Jl@2Xmv0@WkSP4Y1OhSkoEdAilAaHH9VYZIOYnY5YU0WiEsXOKwjAILsHDLAlIMnWgATbAiCfAvOHhHyZmG8U5Fv912V1hgDlTVMtJQ6PwmjCqGBa0oKkccGATQrZDjUtEEFQd8pK65RAieyqKoouE@Uk2XnUZbJCYpv/gfQy1iPTOdBtkhOvrakOCQOVGMfo7KzrPw).

#### Explanation

```
n           % Implicit input: matrix. Push number of elements, N
:           % Range: gives [1 2 ... N]
"           % For each k in [1 2 ... N]
  GG        %   Push input matrix twice
  0@(       %   Write 0 at position k (in column-major order: down, then across).
            %   The stack now contains the original matrix and a modified matrix
            %   with 0 at position k
  ,         %   Do twice
    w       %     Swap
    4       %     Push 4. This specifies 4-element neighbourhood
    &1ZI    %     Label each connected component, using the specified
            %     neighbourhood. This replaces each 1 in the matrix by a
            %     positive integer according to the connected component it
            %     belongs to
    u       %     Unique: gives a vector of deduplicate elements
    z       %     Number of nonzeros. This is the number of connected components
  ]         %   End
  =~        %   Are they different? Gives true of false
]           % End
v           % Concatenate stack into a column vector
GZye        % Reshape (in column-major order) according to size of input matrix.
            % Implicit display
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 40 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
Çóê↓â.Φ}╞│*w<(♦◙¼ñ£º█¢,D`ì♥W4·☺╛gÇÜ♠╗4D┬
```

[Run and debug test cases](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=80a28819832ee87dc6b32a773c28040aaca49ca7db9b2c44608d035734fa01be67809a06bb3444c2&i=%2211101001+11011101+00000001+11101111+11110101+00011111+10110001+11111111%22%0A%221111111111111111+1000000000000001+1111111111111101+0000000000000101+1111111111110101+1000000000010101+1011111111010101+1010000001010101+1010111101010101+1010101111010101+1010100000010101+1010111111110101+1010000000000101+1011111111111101+1000000000000001+1111111111111111%22%0A%221011010001111010+1111111011101101+1110010101001011+1111001110010010+1111010000101001+0111101001000101+0011100111110010+1001110011111110+0101000011100011+1110110101001110+0010100111000110+1000110111011010+0100101000100101+0001010101100011+1001010000111101+1000111011000010%22%0A&a=1&m=2)

This program takes input as a space separated string containing rows.  The output is in the same format.  Here's the unpacked ascii representation.

```
{2%{_xi48&GxG=-}_?m}{'1'2|e{"12|21".22RjMJguHgu%
```

The fundamental operation for counting an island works like this.

1. Replace the first `'1'` with a `'2'`.
2. Regex replace `'12|21'` with `'22'`.
3. Split on spaces.
4. Transpose matrix.
5. Repeat from 2. until a string is repeated.
6. Repeat from 1. until there is no longer a `'1'` in the string.  The number of repetitions is the number of islands.

.

```
{               start map block over input string, composed of [ 01]
  2%            mod by 2. space and 0 yield 0. 1 yields 1. (a)
  {             start conditional block for the 1s.
    _           original char from string (b)
    xi48&       make copy of input with current character replaced with 0
    G           jump to unbalanced }, then return; counts islands (c)
    xG          counts islands in original input (d)
    =           are (c) and (d) equal? 0 or 1 (e)
    -           b - e; this is 1 iff this character is a bridge
  }             end conditional block
  _?            execute block if (a) is 1, otherwise use original char from string
m               close block and perform map over input
}               goto target - count islands and return
{               start generator block
  '1'2|e        replace the first 1 with a 2
  {             start generator block
    "12|21".22R replace "12" and "21" with "22"
    jMJ         split into rows, transpose, and rejoin with spaces
  gu            generate values until any duplicate is encountered
  H             keep the last value
gu              generate values until any duplicate is encountered
%               count number of iterations it took
```

[Bonus 44 byte program](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=8124d11dcf6f6f00efaa77e1ac76c461606012a97a3bae4f55e4efce7d9d9683fe1aad5ae63003c59f5a6955&i=11101001%0A11011101%0A00000001%0A11101111%0A11110101%0A00011111%0A10110001%0A11111111%0A%0A1111111111111111%0A1000000000000001%0A1111111111111101%0A0000000000000101%0A1111111111110101%0A1000000000010101%0A1011111111010101%0A1010000001010101%0A1010111101010101%0A1010101111010101%0A1010100000010101%0A1010111111110101%0A1010000000000101%0A1011111111111101%0A1000000000000001%0A1111111111111111%0A%0A1011010001111010%0A1111111011101101%0A1110010101001011%0A1111001110010010%0A1111010000101001%0A0111101001000101%0A0011100111110010%0A1001110011111110%0A0101000011100011%0A1110110101001110%0A0010100111000110%0A1000110111011010%0A0100101000100101%0A0001010101100011%0A1001010000111101%0A1000111011000010&a=1&m=1) - this version inputs and outputs using the grid format.

Comment: does it process the second example in under a minute on your computer?

Comment: @ngn: It does all three examples in 41s on this mid-range laptop in Chrome.  Also, I just fixed the main link.  I accidentally left it set to an older non-working version.

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), `-p0` <s>105</s> <s>101</s> <s>96</s> <s>93</s> <s>90</s> 89 bytes

Uses `b` instead of `1` in the input.

Make sure the matrix on STDIN is terminated with a newline

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl -p0
s%b%$_="$`z$'";s:|.:/
/>s#(\pL)(.{@{-}}|)(?!\1)(\pL)#$&|a.$2.a#se&&y/{c/z />0:seg&/\B/%eg
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TU/LDoIwELz3K1QKwoF2MPGC8RHP@gck6hpiTIwS60XBX7dCH0of283s7sy0Ku@XqdYqpJDv5iO@f/HxaKbyRuSSyYUK4qLaJLGoV3X6fjdJvBwWWWLAgEfNQfCJOASqjKKnrI/yNZAL5Ko8RbJYy7A8aU2g9gDtYxJGdsFeUAe0VbO7YAAy/bAQc6OAa2KezBJ3APwMuZE@0iYMnoGsGeb14VoZ/nkXDQd6Rg2HoyEv64z/SNHTMZ9zkuTss8@tepxvV6XTCjrdTkUGgS8)

Uses 3 levels of substitution!

This 87 byte version is both in input and output format easier to interpret, but is not competing since it uses 3 different characters in the output:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl -0p
s%b%$_="$`z$'";s:|.:/
/>s#(\w)(.{@{-}}|)(?!\1)(\w)#$&|a.$2.a#se&&y/{c/z />0:seg&/\B/%eg
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TU/LDoIwELz3K1YpCAdaMPGCEY13/4BEXdMQEyPEmhgFf91KX0of283s7sy0FbfLQikZYkj3qyk9vOhsupRFzwpOeCmDuHokMes2Xfp@90m8nlR5orGARv2R0Tk7BlJE0ZN3J/4CXmaFFHXEqy0PRa0UAg4HYHhMQtAusBdQA0PVbB0MgKYfLETcKIBrIp7MEmsA/Ay6kTEyJAQ8A1ozxOuDayXwz3U0HDAyajgcDXpZZ/xHCiMd8zknic7@p2nv5@YqVdpmKt0tWJ6x7As)

It's easy to save another byte (the regex `s` modifier) in both versions by using some different (non-alphanumeric) character as row terminator (instead of newline), but that makes the input quite unreadable again.

## How it works

Consider the substitution

```perl
s#(\w)(.{columns}|)(?!1)(\w)#c$2c#s
```

This will find two letters that are different and next to each other horizontally or vertically and replace them by `c`. In a maze whose paths consist of entirely the letter `b` nothing will happen since the letters are the same, but as soon as one of the letters is replaced by another one (e.g. `z`) that letter and a neighbor will be replaced by `c` and repeated application is a flood-fill of the connected component with `c` from seed `z`.

In this case I however don't want a complete flood-fill. I want to fill only one of the arms neighboring `z`, so after the first step I want the `z` gone. That already works with the `c$2c` replacement, but I later want to restart a flood-fill along another arm starting from the same point and I don't know which of the `c`s was originally `z` anymore. So instead I use

```perl
s#(\w)(.{columns}|)(?!\1)(\w)#$&|a.$2.a#se
```

`b | a` is `c`, `b | c` is `c` and `z | a` is `{`. So in a maze with paths made up of `b` and a seed `z` in the first step `b` will get replaced by `c` and `z` will get replaced by `{` which is not a letter and does not match `\w` and so will not cause further fills. The `c` however will keep a further flood-fill going and one neighbor arm of the seed gets filled. E.g. starting from

```perl
  b                      c
  b                      c
bbzbb       becomes    bb{bb
  b                      b
  b                      b
```

I can then replace all c by some non letter (e.g. `-`) and replace `{` by `z` again to restart the flood-fill:

```perl
  -                      -
  -                      -
bbzbb       becomes    cc{bb
  b                      b
  b                      b
```

and repeat this process until all neighbors of the seed have been converted. If I then once more replace `{` by `z` and flood-fill:

```perl
  -                      -
  -                      -
--z--       stays      --z--
  -                      -
  -                      -
```

The `z` remains behind at the end because there is no neighbor to do a transformation with.
That makes clear what happens in the following code fragment:

```perl
/\n/ >
```

Find the first newline. The starting offset is now in `@-`

```perl
s#(\w)(.{@{-}}|)(?!\1)(\w)#$&|a.$2.a#se
```

The regex discussed above with `@{-}` as number of columns (since plain `@-` confuses the perl parser and doesn't properly substitute)

```perl
&&
```

The `/\n/` always succeeds and the substitution is true as long as we can still flood-fill. So the part after `&&` is executed if the flood-fill of one arm is done. If not the left side evaluates to an empty string

```perl
y/{c/z / > 0
```

Restart the flood-fill and return 1 if the previous flood-fill did anything. Else return the empty string. This whole piece of code is wrapped inside

```perl
s:|.: code :seg
```

So if this is executed on a starting string `$_` with a `z` at the seed position the piece of code inside will be executed many times mostly returning nothing but a `1` every time a neighbor arm gets flood-filled. Effectively `$_` gets destroyed and replaced by as many `1`s as there are connected components attached to `z`. Notice that the loop needs to be executed up to sum of component sizes + number of arms times but that is OK since it will "number of characters including newlines * 2 + 1" times.

The maze gets disconnected if there are no `1`'s (empty string, an isolated vertex) or if there are more than 1 arms (more than 2 `1`s). This can be checked using the regex `/\B/` (this gives `0` instead of `1` on older perl versions. It's arguable which one is wrong). Unfortunately if it doesn't match this will give an empty string instead of `0`. However the `s:|.: code :seg` was designed to always return an odd number so by doing an `&` with `/\B/` this will give `0` or `1`.

All that is left is walking the whole input array and at each walkable position seed with `z` and count connected arms. That is easily done with:

```perl
s%b%$_="$`z$'"; code %eg
```

The only problem is that in the non-walkable positions the old value is retained. Since we need `0`s there that means the original input array must have `0` in the non walkable positions and `0` matches `\w` in the original substitution and would trigger flood-fills. That's why I use `\pL` instead (only match letters).

Answer (score 2):

## Java 8, <s>503</s> <s>489</s> <s>459</s> <s>455</s> 407 bytes

```java
int R,C,v[][];m->{int r[][]=new int[R=m.length][C=m[0].length],i=R*C,a=i(m),x,y,q;for(;i-->0;m[y][x]=0,r[y][x]=i(m)!=a?1:0,m[y][x]=q)q=m[y=i/C][x=i%C];return r;}int i(int[][]m){int r=0,i=R*C,x,y;for(v=new int[R][C];i-->0;)if(m[y=i/C][x=i%C]>v[y][x]){d(m,x,y);r++;}return r;}void d(int[][]m,int c,int r){v[r][c]=1;for(int k=-3,x,y;k<4;k+=2)if((x=c+k%2-k/2)>=0&x<C&(y=r+k/2)>=0&y<R&&m[y][x]>v[y][x])d(m,x,y);}
```

-66 bytes thanks to *@ceilingcat*.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##rVbNk5owFL/vX5HuzDqhBA12TxtjD5566LbjHhkOLOJuVNDFaGUc/nY3gYAgScuhE@Uj7@P3ey/vkayCY@Bsd1GyWqwv4SbY78HPgCXnOwBYwqN0GYQReJavxYTnez4IYfUUW0RI8rtSG8zRDB2lgEj10QjY7iN4zXi0B3wL@HtUvDjh9pBwafMMEkDBJXamZ2meSlOaRH8KpDmNh5soeePvvjejsYf96hUxOv86QwFlMLbQCWXogyy3KSTMcaaYxF7meyefYpSqJ6n3hQbf3SeMKumH9SGcZpSNZuKdsoeZT9KIH9IEpCQnkg@r4oytkp9wWUILzALxeGUrSPqKgMWW8Mb19FjCWucFjKW5RVLbJvkV8bhlC7CoEZEEDItrap2PXup7oU/dAlVOrqnzraCxnjyStU3HEhSeaGivH8bOejS2phQPTpPZAGY0tauJbDIfDFQKak41pfwCwO7wumEh2POAi1vBKhYFAV94ypI3zw@sshjEonJYRS8Yl7MAnF0kBy7@4pqjpgCjWnwVYNQcNxZXm46gQum4cnUWWFloMa4WeVHS/4zPONqQ5mGm0Bp/SVTLWz@PGkWjt66iwZtOUetNr6jxZlLE/aDdfsHgfulx@yUc91vC/1IUPesUtzrxJnkmJNy6a9uxvVJ1KnXtiVHbyADdzLL223G78s2gOi1yC@7qoU2qblsRd/i5zYzqv1bt9HQ8asT1M@4Wi3ZduhzxzWpj8/ex3VHaYDDSR24o6Da7GkfVaS7@4tfcVYrCrQ4SLNkduNpZXrI9j@Lh9sCHO7Hn8E0C739I@RO4V0W/E/smz35LKSxNidH014EbbWXfyOMOtIbJMFSuzL6up51mIG0y6mAUiO3ypAISezaAS5YEm7JJQbSJ4khs4k@VHqi6ttreVxST1UTpqXMPWdm2pfS69KBS9la@CsAcQrke@V1@@QQ)

**Explanation:**

```java
int R,C,                    // Amount of rows/columns on class-level
    v[][];                  // Visited-matrix on class-level

m->{                        // Method with int-matrix as both parameter and return-type
  int r[][]=new int[R=m.length][C=m[0].length],
                            //  Create the result-matrix, and set `R` and `C`
      i=R*C,                //  Index-integer
      a=i(m),               //  The current amount of islands
      x,y,                  //  Temp integers for the coordinates
      q;                    //  Temp integer for the value
  for(;i-->0                //  Loop `i` over each cell:
      ;                     //    After each iteration:
       m[y][x]=0,           //     Temporarily change the current value to 0
       r[y][x]=i(m)!a?      //     If the current and initial amount of islands are not
                            //     the same anymore:
                1           //      Set the result-value at this coordinate to 1
               :            //     Else:
                0,          //      Set the result-value at this coordinate to 0
       m[y][x]=q)           //     Then change the current value back to what it was
    q=m[y=i/C][x=i%C];      //   Save the current value at this coordinate
  return r;}                //  Return the result-matrix

// Separated method to determine the amount of islands in a matrix
int i(int[][]m){
  int r=0,                  //  Result-count, starting at 0
      i=R*C,                //  Index integer
      x,y;                  //  Temp integers for the coordinates
  for(v=new int[R][C];      //  Reset the visited array
      i-->0;)               //  Loop over the cells:
    if(m[y=i/C][x=i%C]      //   If the current cell is a 1,
       >v[y][x]){           //   and we haven't visited it yet:
      d(m,x,y);             //    Check every direction around this cell
      r++;}                 //    And raise the result-counter by 1
   return r;}               //  Return the result-counter

// Separated method to check each direction around a cell
void d(int[][]m,int c,int r){
  v[r][c]=1;                //  Flag this cell as visited
  for(int k=-3,x,y;k<4;k+=2)//  Loop over the four directions:
    if((x=c+k%2-k/2)>=0&x<C&(y=r+k/2)>=0&y<R
                            //   If the cell in the direction is within bounds,
       &&m[y][x]            //   and it's a path we can walk,
         >v[y][x])          //   and we haven't visited it yet:
      d(m,x,y);}            //    Do a recursive call for this cell
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 290 bytes

```python
lambda m:[[b([[C and(I,J)!=(i,j)for J,C in e(R)]for I,R in e(m)])!=b(eval(`m`))for j,c in e(r)]for i,r in e(m)]
def F(m,i,j):
	if len(m)>i>=0<=j<len(m[i])>0<m[i][j]:m[i][j]=0;F(m,i,j+1);F(m,i,j-1);F(m,i+1,j);F(m,i-1,j)
b=lambda m:sum(F(m,i,j)or c for i,r in e(m)for j,c in e(r))
e=enumerate
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XVBNb8MgDD0vv4L1BKo7kR3TkEulSe2xV4ZU0hCNKJCIppv26zPIV7PKAj/7PRvj9rf7aux7X7LPvpYmLyQyCec55vyApC3wEU7klWENFSkbh05wQNoihc9EhPgI5zE2RHhdjtW3rPHFXMggr@A60m6Ua3CLPCpUiT6wgdA7iV50iWplPZPpjNGUVekQci1IRtPgeSWSyTO6n0q3MZnhbobb2Lcc4S7AKGfL5253g@dX/URX9DTX09gkUkzZu1FOdqoPpGt@Aln6FcUQjA7H3wIiPicmH1IU1raoHrpVau62Koz/q@ikeur1UImwzNZp26EN2rxVjfZblC2@dQ5QAJ6B8AtCSP8H)

-11 bytes thanks to Rod
-11 bytes thanks to Lynn

Comment: It's shorter to use `F(m,i,j)` for each element, [saving 11 bytes](https://tio.run/##XVBNb8MgDD0vv4LdYHUlot2y0kulSe2xV8YhaUAlKiRlqab9@gznq1lkgZ/t92xD89tea//eGfHV3XJXlDlxmZQFlfJAcl/SI5zYq6AWKmbqQE5wINYTTc9MYXyE8xA7piIv6u4y6yt3zDvVqyq4DKwwqCyEWZWU2pBP6gBHZMmLNeSmfazs7V7wnah2fSitYnEfgkBWKhu94B@jdpOyCW4nuEljzwFuESaFmB/5/XBUTnMVtr6Q1W6r1VmihfYPp0Pe6g6Lof7Boom/lQIa70@8FSRySoweUxyWNrOevEVq6rYQpv9ZfGStej1ZCj@0Cda39M3lDY0AcGnGuj8)

Comment: `for q in((i,j+1),(i,j-1),(i+1,j),(i-1,j)):` -> `for q in(i,j+1),(i,j-1),(i+1,j),(i-1,j):` - rm outer parens

Comment: Since `F` implicitly returns `None`, you can use `F(m,i,j)or c` instead of `[F(m,i,j)]and c`.

Comment: Also, `and m[i][j]` can be `>0<m[i][j]`, and `[q[:]for q in m]` can be ``eval(`m`)``.

Comment: @Lynn you mean eval('m')? wouldn't that return the same list instance?

Comment: @ngn no, `eval('m')` would return the same instance (but it doesn't even work because of scoping). `eval(\`m\`)` basically is just stringifying `m` and then `eval`ing it again

Comment: @HyperNeutrino oh, I see... Thanks. I guess my python3 is too old, it fails with a SyntaxError.

Comment: @ngn no actually python 3 is too new. the backtick thing was removed in python 3.

Comment: @HyperNeutrino One of the many reasons why Python 2 is superior ...

Answer (score 1):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 118 bytes

```
(r=ReplacePart)[0#,Cases[#~Position~1,p_/;(c=Max@MorphologicalComponents[#,CornerNeighbors->1<0]&)@r[#,p->0]>c@#]->1]&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY3BCoMwEER/RRBEIdJ4bpWAZ4v0KqGkEjWg2RBzKIj@eqoUaSzCsgwz@2YHZjo@MCNqZhsvtaFOH1z1rOYl0yaqsI9yNvKx8pcSRmEEyCVB6nm5hnVasDcpQKsOemjXhj6HQYHk0qz3KActub5z0XYv0GOcJTdMg4joNVNxhmlWE5@uNg1sqYU0pCHTlCDvO3jfm5iRN7n2T28J3u/ccZg/7Ji4r45tyQmDHebsz5GZ7Qc)

Answer (score 1):

## Javascript 122 bytes

Input/output as a multiline string.

```js
m=>m.replace(/./g,(v,p,m,n=[...m],f=p=>n[p]==1&&(n[p]=0,v=f(p-1)+f(p+1)+f(p-w)+f(p+w)-1?1:0,1))=>(f(p),v),w=~m.search`\n`)
```

For each walkable cell, put a block and try to fill the 4 neighbor cells. If the current cell is not a cut point, then starting from any open neighbor will fill all of them. Else, I will need more than one fill operation to reach all neighbor cells.

*Less golfed*

```js
m=>{
  w = m.search('\n') + 1; // offset to the next row
  result = [...m].map( // for each cell
     ( v, // current value
       p  // current position
     ) => {
     n = [...m]; // work on a copy of the input
     // recursive fill function from position p
     // returns 1 if managed to fill at least 1 cell
     fill = (p) => {
        if (n[p] == 1)
        {
           n[p] = 0;
           // flag will be > 1 if the fill from the current point found disjointed areas
           // flag will be 0 if no area could be filled (isolated cell)
           var flag = fill(p+1) + fill(p-1) + fill(p+w) + fill(p-w);
           // v is modified repeatedly, during recursion
           // but I need the value at top level, when fill returns to original caller
           v = flag != 1 ? 1 : 0;
           return 1; // at least 1 cell filled
        }
        else
           return 0; // no fill
     }
     fill(p)
     return v // orginal value or modified by fill function
  }) 
}
```

**Test**

```js
var F=
m=>m.replace(/./g,(v,p,m,n=[...m],f=p=>n[p]==1&&(n[p]=0,v=f(p-1)+f(p+1)+f(p-w)+f(p+w)-1?1:0,1))=>(f(p),v),w=~m.search`\n`)

var test=`in:
11101001
11011101
00000001
11101111
11110101
00011111
10110001
11111111
out:
01000000
00001001
00000001
00000101
00110000
00010000
00000000
11100000

in:
1111111111111111
1000000000000001
1111111111111101
0000000000000101
1111111111110101
1000000000010101
1011111111010101
1010000001010101
1010111101010101
1010101111010101
1010100000010101
1010111111110101
1010000000000101
1011111111111101
1000000000000001
1111111111111111
out:
0000000000000000
0000000000000000
0000000000000000
0000000000000000
0000000000000000
0000000000000000
0000000000000000
0000000000000000
0000000000000000
0000000000000000
0000000000000000
0000000000000000
0000000000000000
0000000000000000
0000000000000000
0000000000000000

in:
1011010001111010
1111111011101101
1110010101001011
1111001110010010
1111010000101001
0111101001000101
0011100111110010
1001110011111110
0101000011100011
1110110101001110
0010100111000110
1000110111011010
0100101000100101
0001010101100011
1001010000111101
1000111011000010
out:
0000000000111010
1011110001001000
0000000000000011
0000000100010000
0000010000101000
0000001000000100
0000000011000000
1001100000011110
0000000001000010
0110100001000110
0000100101000010
1000100000000000
0100001000000100
0000000100100001
0000010000111000
0000010000000010
`.match(/\d[10\n]+\d/g);
for(i = 0; test[2*i]; ++i)
{
   input = test[2*i]
   check = test[2*i+1]
   result = F(input)
   ok = check == result
   console.log('Test '+ i + ' ' + (ok?'OK':'FAIL'),
   '\n'+input, '\n'+result)
}
```